# Added scripts do not appear in HTML when visiting site

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

**DNN Version: 04.09.05** (yes, I know it's old. This is one of the oldest sites maintained by the company I work for)

I'm not entirely sure what code to include here, since it seems almost irrelevant. Here's my issue:

I have added a mobile redirect script to a the skin.ascx for a DNN site:

```
<%@ Control language="vb" CodeBehind="~/admin/Skins/skin.vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGO" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Logo.ascx" %> <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SOLPARTMENU" Src="~/Admin/Skins/SolPartMenu.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="USER" Src="~/Admin/Skins/User.ascx" %> <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGIN" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Login.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="CURRENTDATE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/CurrentDate.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LANGUAGE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Language.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="SEARCH" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Search.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="BREADCRUMB" Src="~/Admin/Skins/BreadCrumb.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LINKS" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Links.ascx" %> <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="COPYRIGHT" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Copyright.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TERMS" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Terms.ascx" %> <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="PRIVACY" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Privacy.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="HELP" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Help.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="HOUSEMENU" Src="~/DesktopModules/HouseMenuSkinObject/HouseMenuSkinObject.ascx" %>

<!-- Mobile Redirect -->
<script src="/Portals/_default/skins/*********/scripts/redirection-mobile.js"></script>
<script>
    SA.redirection_mobile();
</script>
<!-- / Mobile Redirect -->    

<!-- www.DotNetNukeSkin.com, www.DNNSource.com, www.DNNBlast.com -->
```

but despite my efforts to clear the DNN cache and even restart the application, this never appears when visiting the site.

Here's what I see where that script *should* be:

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=Vfg8rdbqjJxftEOai7TpkVMgS5M3EpWnLJOIYxski_LUgp8dX_IpQo23OtpIMPbl9BRn7Gvd5xGcDwPU0&amp;t=635359717876031270" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/js/dnncore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=EHk-FrMHceUyqcY0-Ou7uoHZdqiXevkiBXGM4IwtB9QaoQazyRuYSotYRd4XIARQzPydSQ5xOERE5RYgV-OvRozQDW8PaDmPnWhQI1UYydn9DyMcGUSN9-XtqJ5WOQA1G57ez5pQ9bzPvHpo6Wyh8yUGgFY1&amp;t=ffffffffa37d832a" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=aMtM2AA2yI3ghP5Pe-NcoK-AYskpYVGguYXvrwDo1MUnUBn18bqEEGw8_GdcQ79Ecs7d5GcFroKs5--e-ZmUr3jRRMfTGboqIz4N8yPYJIojGGy6AnIDkQR4Hp1W3z4jIWzDpSXifOa6inrF-rghB-sjnyjG9wsURK0oHw2&amp;t=ffffffffa37d832a" type="text/javascript"></script>



<!-- www.DotNetNukeSkin.com, www.DNNSource.com, www.DNNBlast.com -->
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically need to verify that ANYTHING you put into the HTML shows up. I imagine that you will find that it won't.

If that's the case, you'll need to track down which Skin is actually in use, and make sure you're changing the right one.

The skin could be in the path you mention above
/portals/_default/skins/skinname/

but it could also be pulling from

/portals/#/skins/skinname where # is the ID of the Portal.

So basically, start by verifying you're in the right place, then make changes from there. The HTML you're putting in shouldn't cause any problems with DNN itself, so that leads me to believe you're simply not looking in the right place..

Comment: I think this is the case. I am going to wait until after hours today and see if I can "break" it by removing the files and doing some extra digging.

Comment: You nailed it. I was in the correct parent directory, but the home page was using a different skin than the rest of the site. I was making changes to `/skins/{my_site}` when I should have been changing `/skins/{my_site}_front`. #facepalm